# Hosting rails app on Windows with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, apache, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What is the recommended approach to host rails on windows using Apache?

I googled a lot but most links recommend mod_rails for integrating Apache with Rails. However the links are for Linux and not windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a stable deployment on Windows, your best bet would be `JRuby` and a `J2EE` container such as tomcat. Apache Http server can proxy to tomcat and several other j2ee containers

There are some newer options such as [TorqueBox](http://torquebox.org/). This [guide](http://torquebox.org/builds/LATEST/getting-started/first-steps.html#first-steps-windows) may help

Answer (score 0):

Is this for local development or for actually running a public accessible server?

Look at [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Once you have that running, follow [Eternal-Learner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19180931/385532). I originally suggested Mongrel but that seems to have been replaced by [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/).

Comment: It is a publicly accessible server and I already have Apache installed on it hosting PHP applications

Comment: @Eternal-Learner Thanks, I have updated my answer to maintain original apache context but point to yours for server details.